# Have code excecute after x seconds - Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have a method execute every second by using an additional class that `extends TimerTask`. I think the reason that it doesn't work is that I'm trying to execute a method that eventually returns a value back to the MainActivity. This is why: I tested the code by making the method not return anything (just print something to the console) and it worked.

Here's a summary of what my code looks like with the returning method:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new doStuff(), 0, 1000);
}

public void method1(String string){
    //things happen
}

}

//----------------------------------------

class doStuff extends TimerTask{

@Override
public void run(){

    String string = stringMethod(); 
    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
    ma.method1(string);        
}

    public String stringMethod(){
        //gets the required string
        return "String";
    }
}
```

Note that the method itself doesn't return a value directly to `MainActivity`. `run()` does that.

When I try to run the code on my Android Device, LogCat says something about `notify()` not blocking something. Not sure. Can't remember.
I just want to know if there's an easier way that doesn't require two classes before I tackle this.

*Sorry about the stupid names. I just made them for demo purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a handler:

```
final Handler handler=new Handler();

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        //This will run every 1000ms. Put code here(UI safe)
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Comment: I pasted your code into Android Studio, and it underlines `handler` from `handler.postDelay(this, 1000)` and says: `Error:(56, 17) error: local variable handler is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final`. How should I fix this?

**EDIT:** I put `final` in front of `Handler handler=new Handler();` and it works! Thank you!

Comment: It reports the solution. Make it final: final handler = new Handler()